# Methodology: Recursive datasets - tree branch refinement

Tags: python, methodology

I have a number of sets of data. These sets contain numbers that specify how much points a user gains upon passing to the next index:

```
A = (2,[2],2,6,6,10)
B = (2,4,[4],2,5,7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,[4],5,6,7,7,8,10)
```

In this example I use three sets but in the real problem it are far more sets (a variable amount). The [square] brackets mean that that is the current selected index, so the indexes specified above are: `(1,2,2)`
All these indexes together form a total that I can keep track of by grabbing it from a webpage (in this case the total is: `(2+2)+(2+4+4)+(2+3+4) = 23`). By keeping track of the total I know that the total changes with a number, let's call this number X.

```
Total:   23 -> 25 -> 30
X:          +2   +5       (these are the numbers X I can keep track of, they are given, but variable)
```

In this example the first X is +2, this either means that A went from 1->2 or B from 2->3:

Case 1: A passes on

```
A = (2,2,[2],6,6,10)
B = (2,4,[4],4,5,7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,[4],5,6,7,7,8,10)
```

Case 2: B passes on

```
A = (2,[2],2,6,6,10)
B = (2,4,4,[2],5,7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,[4],5,6,7,7,8,10)
```

We know the next increase is +5, this either means that for case 1, C goes from 2 -> 3 or for case 2: B 3->4 or C 2 -> 3

Case 1: A increased => C increased

```
A = (2,2,[2],6,6,10)
B = (2,4,4,[2],5,7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,4,[5],6,7,7,8,10)
```

Case 2: B increased => B increased

```
A = (2,[2],2,6,6,10)
B = (2,4,4,2,[5],7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,[4],5,6,7,7,8,10)
```

Case 3: B increased => C increased

```
A = (2,[2],2,6,6,10)
B = (2,4,4,[2],5,7,7,6,10,12,10,6)
C = (2,3,4,[5],6,6,7,8,10)
```

Now what I need to write an algorithm for is to display EVERY possible combination of indexes as a result of the increases `I=(+2,+5)`, note that it in reality these are variables: `I=(+X, +Y, +Z, ...)` and the depth is also variable.

Now the problem looks quite easy, but imagine the next increase being 7 resulting in `I=(+2,+5,+7)`, then there only remains 1 case valid (B->B->B). In some way I thus need to write a big recursive function that re-evaluates all results and removes dead ends, for every following increase, but I'm not sure how to write such a function.

For extra clarification: imagine the tracked data going +2, +5, +6, +6 then this diagram shows me what I want accomplished: [image: Tree diagram]

**Summary:** The full problem with all its variables is thus:

N Sets of data:

```
A = (a1,a2,a3,a4,...)
B = (b1,b2,b3,b4,...)
...
N = (n1,n2,n3,n4,...)
```

A given array Z with the current selected indexes:

```
Z = ([A], [B], [C], ... , [N])
```

A given array I with increases with depth N:

```
I = (+X,+Y,...,+N)
```

**Asked:** possible new arrays Z (possible ways to get to the new total with given intervals using only the increases specified in the data sets)

**What I want:** How to write an algorithm for this purpose, I don't need you to write the algorithm, but a starting points would be nice, I'm kinda lost in the problem.

*Note: due to this question being quite long and technical, it is possible that some minor mistakes got in, comment below and I'll try to solve them*

Comment: You might want to consider removing the unnecessarily specific information about why you are doing this. It would make it easier to read.

Comment: I already simplified the problem as much as possible, but I'll look into it tonight and try to cleanse my question of a "storyline"

Comment: I rewrote it, I think it's better now